# How do I make a vba do this?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been building a dashboard as a tooling checkout sheet. The data output to the logbook works fine.  I have not been able to figure out how to implement my next step yet.  I want to find a way to put a "check in" date to the logbook to finalize the procedure.

I want to know what an efficient way to reference sheet1;e10 to sheet2;columnB would be.

**Pseudocode**:

```
if column (i) is empty or 0 then
  =today() in sheet2;same row column (i).
endif"
```

I want to assign this a macro to a button.  I did the same for the checkout procedure.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking - it seems you want to check if each row of a column is empty, and if so you want to put today's date into the same row of a column in a different sheet? Am I correct in my assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly:

```
Sheets("Table1").Range("B1").Value = "Logging date: " & Now
```

This little snippet puts the text "Logging date: 10.06.2015 09:30:21" in the field at B1. Another possibility is to use Cells(rowIndex,colIndex), in this case Cells(1,2) which is less understandable in my opinion.

As I can only guess, what your pseudocode should do, here my interpretation:

```
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer
row = 1
col = 2

If (IsEmpty(Cells(row, col)) Or Cells(row, col).Value = "0") Then
    Sheets("Table1").Range("B1").Value = "Logging date: " & Now
Else
    'whatever you want to do otherwise
End If
```

Do not expect it to be solving your problem instantly. But maybe this is a first starting point for you?